# How to make a function return nothing?

Tags: python

I have a function called `crawl` which will return a link to a website. Then I do something like:

`found.append(crawl())` (found is a list)

This works fine as long as crawl returns a valid link, but sometimes it does not return anything. So a value of `None` gets added to the list.

So my question is that, is it possible to return something from `crawl` that will not not add anything to the list?

Comment: As a footnote, this sounds like a terrible question.

Comment: No, it's not possible simply because `None` *is* nothing. The best you can do is `retval = crawl(); if retval: found.append(retval)`.

Comment: Although technically you have to return something, even if it is `None`, I disagree that for *practical* purposes checking for `None` is not the only possibility. Raising an exception rather than returning `None` is a very reasonable thing to do when a problem is encountered by a function that a list is being built from. If the condition causing `return None` or an exception is uncommon, exception handling can have better performance than checking for `None`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python nothing is something: `None`. You have to use if-condition:

```
link = crawl()
if link is not None:
    found.append(link)
```

or let `crawl` return a list, which can contain one or zero elements:

```
found.extend(crawl())
```

Comment: Hmm. I like the second idea.

Comment: What is this `expand` function? I get an exception when trying to use it.

Comment: It should be `extend`. I corrected it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to pass the list in to the crawl function and if there is anything to add append it otherwise not. Something like:

```
def crawl(found):
   """ Add results to found list """
   # do your stuff saving to result
   if result is not None:
       found.append(result)

# Call this as 
   crawl(found)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible directly.

You can test for a `None` being returned though, using the following code.

```
returned_link = crawl()
if returned_link is not None:
    found.append(returned_link)
```

Comment: `if returned_link:` might wrongly skip an append if `crawl` can return, eg, the empty string. If you want to test for `None`, it's better to be explicit: `if returned_link is not None:`

Comment: @lvc, thanks for that. Didn't realize that empty strings would affect the condition. Edited the answer to reflect the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If a function returns it has to return an object, even if that object is `None`. However, there is another answer being overlooked, and that is to raise an exception rather than returning `None`.

As other people point out, one approach is to check if the returned object is `None` before appending it to the list:

```
link = crawl()
if link is not None:
    found.append(link)
```

The other approach is to define some exception, perhaps `WebsiteNotFoundError`, and have `crawl` execute `raise WebsiteNotFoundError` instead of `return None`. Then you can write:

```
try:
    found.append(crawl())
except WebsiteNotFoundError:
    pass  # or take appropriate action
```

The advantage of the exception handling approach is that it is generally faster than checking for `None` if returning `None` is a relatively rare occurrence compared to returning a valid link. Depending on the use, it may be more readable in the sense that the code naturally explains what is going wrong with the function.